# Any idea on why my container is overlapping my header?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out why my container is overlapping my header when it comes to the small screen section. My goal is for the container (and all the contents inside of it) to be underneath my header on the page. It works perfectly for the extra small screen part, but the small screen is where it all goes wrong. I am just beginning my journey into bootstrap so please ignore my sloppy code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid-system-test.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="d-sm-none">   <!-- Navbar is only viewable on extra small screens -->
        <div class="white-block">
            <img class="comp-logo mx-auto d-block" src="img/logo.png" alt="company logo">
        </div>
        <nav class="text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="thin-font">codeup design</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul class="nav xs-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>SERVICES</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>WORK</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>BLOG</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>CONTACT</p></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block"> <!------------------------ NAVBAR FOR SMALL SCREEN STARTS HERE -------------------------->
        <nav class="white-bg text-center small-nav">

            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                <li class="small-nav-item">
                    <a class="small-nav-link" href="#">SERVICE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="small-nav-item">
                    <a class="small-nav-link" href="#">WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="small-nav-item">
                    <a class="small-nav-link" href="#"><img class="comp-logo comp-logo-small" src="img/logo.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="small-nav-item">
                    <a class="small-nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="small-nav-item">
                    <a class="small-nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="thin-font">codeup design</h2>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>


<!-------------------------------------------- CONTAINER STARTS HERE -------------------------------------------------->

    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h2>VISUAL DESIGN & WEB DEVELOPMENT</h2>
        <h4 class="park-city-text">FROM PARK CITY, UTAH</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="circle-big red-bg ml-4">
                    <h6 class="text-light center-txt">DESIGN</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="circle-big orange-bg mr-4">
                    <h6 class="text-light center-txt">DEVELOP</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="circle-big green-bg ml-4 circle-margin-top">
                    <h6 class="text-light center-txt">SUPPORT</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="circle-big blue-bg mr-3 circle-margin-top">
                    <h6 class="text-light center-txt">HOST</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of circle images -->

        <p class="selectW">SELECTED WORK</p>
        <img class="ipad rounded" src="img/apple-ipad.jpg" alt="apple on ipad">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <p class="float-left ml-3">FEATURED PROJECT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="circle-sm red-bg small-circle-text float-right mr-2"><p class="font-weight-bold">D</p></div>
                <div class="circle-sm orange-bg small-circle-text float-right mr-2"><p class="font-weight-bold">D</p></div>
                <div class="circle-sm green-bg small-circle-text float-right mr-2"><p class="font-weight-bold">S</p></div>
                <div class="circle-sm blue-bg small-circle-text float-right mr-2"><p class="font-weight-bold">H</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way I already fixed all the columns that did not have rows. That did not help my situation.

Comment: Don't forget to create a fiddle to help us help you !

Comment: You should not create 2 navigations but apply responsive classes to show and hide what you need for each breakpoint.